# 960 Grid: the proper way to make grid lists

Tags: css, 960.gs

When using the 960 grid, what is the proper way to make lists of information?  By lists of information, I am specifically referring to a list of data you would show a user on a page, not a listbox or html control.

For example, go to the main page (http://stackoverflow.com/) and look at the list of 'Top Questions'.  I want to achieve the same type of list, but using 960gs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

960gs is just a way to divide a page into grids to but different sections of content in. Once you start putting content into those sections, it becomes more or less irrelevant.

If you have a list of data, then use standard list markup — a `<ul>` or `<ol>` containing one or more `<li>` elements.

If you have tabular data (as per your example), then use table markup — a `<table>` with appropriate `<caption>`, `<thead>`, `<tfoot>`, `<tbody>`, `<tr>`, `<th>` and `<td>` elements.

Comment: Quentin is right, the grid systems helps you to define zones/regions/..., the actual content (such as your list) shouldn't even be related. The list will eventually reside inside some div with a `grid-8` class e.g., but the list itself doesn't need any grid classes.

Comment: Perfect.  thanks to both of you - that's the conclusion I kept running into but I was fighting using css and tables to style a list because it was using the 960gs.  Thanks!

Comment: @Paul I agree with both of you, but the example that the OP used doesn't follow those guidelines. The stackoverflow homepage is using divs and some custom css.

Comment: @guanome — The question asks what the proper way is. Stackoverflow is not an example of good use of web technologies.

Answer (score -1):

You could wrap your list in `<div class="container_12">` then iterate over `<div class="grid_12 row">` for each item you have in your list

http://jsfiddle.net/Zm627/1/

```
<div class="container_12">
  <div class="grid_12 row">
      <div class="grid_1 alpha">
            1 Vote          
      </div>
      <div class="grid_1">
            1 Answer
      </div>
      <div class="grid_1">
            17 Views
      </div>
      <div class="grid_9 omega">
          <div class="grid_12">
              <div class="grid_6">
                    Find variations between two database tables effciently
              </div>    
          </div>

          <div class="grid_12">
              <div class="grid_6">
                  <button>sql-server</button>                                                      
                  <button>database</button>
                  <button>tsql</button>
                  <button>replication</button>
              </div>    
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>​
```